# Factorisation algorithm for polynomials in several variables over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, factoring

What algorithm is used by a CAS to decide how to factor a polynomial in several variables over $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: [Translation:](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Mit%20welchem%20Algorithmus%20entscheidet%20ein%20CAS%2C%20ob%20und%20wie%20ein%20Polynom%20in%20mehreren%20Variablen%20%C3%BCber%20Z%20faktorisierbar%20ist%3F) With which algorithm decides a CAS whether and how a polynomial is factored in several variables over Z?

Comment: @Shaun Thanks. I truly did not notice in which language I was writing. I shouldn't switch too much between languages ...

Comment: You're welcome. That's rather impressive :)

Comment: *Modern Computer Algebra* by Joachim von zur Gathen & Jürgen Gerhard may help you. Chapter 15 has something related to this.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for the reference, I will look into it.